# Prefer fulfilling some requests over others

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

We have setup a server to run our rails 3 app.  Some of the webpages in our app have to process a lot of data and take a long time to complete, a few of them even take as much as 10 minutes to complete.

Our server is setup to only fulfill six requests at a time.  Occasionally, during peak usage, the server ends up getting bogged down for several minutes because the requests it is fulfilling are those that take a long time.

Almost every request that is capable of taking more than a handful of seconds has a route like domain/reports/some_thing.

**So anyway, I was going through the [design and architecture documentation](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Design%20and%20Architecture.html), specifically sections 3.1.2 and 3.2, and was wondering if it was possible to configure the ApplicationPool to prefer some sessions over others when it is deciding what session to return to the RequestsHelper (primarily based on the request url being /reports/*)?**

Probably only allowing 4 of the 6 processes to handle requests with a url like /reports/* would be ideal.  However, simply preferring all other requests above those with a url like /reports/* would probably be pretty practical.

P.S. I have only just started working with the server aspect of this application.  Let me know if there is an easier way, if you need more details, or very likely, if I'm asking about X...

P.P.S. I am going to be revisiting the pages that are slow in an effort to minimize the number of requests of this type that are made by implementing some things with a more client side approach and possibly by implementing a post/redirect/get structure for these pages as well, however, this will take time and will only make the issue less frequent...

Comment: What about background processes for long running jobs?

Comment: We are using delayed_jobs gem, so it might be an option to pass render for the report into a delayed_job which is what I had in mind when I mentioned reworking the pages into a post/redirect/get structure.  It could take a while to get that working though, and a post/redirect/get structure is rather different from how we have things set up currently...

Comment: @BradWerth possibly, it is worth noting that the reports that are generated are html pages though, and that I am concerned with minimizing any changes to the ui if possible... much of our user base does not own a computer outside of work

Comment: @BradWerth, right and I probably will end up implementing that approach... but I'm a rather curious person... and even with a working solution, now that I've asked the question, I'm rather curious about it... is it possible to prefer certain requests with phusion passenger, such that if those requests are in the queue, they get fulfilled first (or last)? (or possibly why this is a poor approach)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phusion Passenger author here. What you could do is to split your application into multiple application process groups, using the [passenger_app_group_name](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/blob/63358eea7de616600fc04df8188b84a1a7ea43b1/doc/Users%20guide%20Nginx.txt#L652-L734) directive, say for one /reports and one for everything else. That way you will end up with one request queue per application process group. If one the URLs for /reports takes longer to respond, then they won't affect the requests for all the other URLs.

Using a worker queue system, like others suggested, is also a valid approach. That way you move the blocking away from the HTTP server and into an external system.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  But I was having some difficulties wording my question in a way that didn't turn up some variation of the worker queue system.  Our user base is not the most technically savvy, so the necessary changes to the UI to implement a worker queue system are a con with more weight than you might think.  Anyway, thanks a bunch for your answer.  That page you linked to is extremely insightful.